# Variant Manager Missing from Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

After watching some videos on how to use variant subsystems in a design, I was able to get variants working.

But [this video](http://www.mathworks.com/videos/managing-design-variants-68948.html) tutorial (Managing Design Variants) from Mathworks mentions a Variant Manager which I have been unable to find in my version of Simulink. I am running version R2011b.

My View menu is different form the one in the tutorial, but it shows tabs for the Library browser, the Model Explorer and the Simulink Project. But I don't see any sign of a Variant Manager. I checked the other menu tabs with the same results.

Documentation help doesn't find anything on Variant Manager either.

Is the Variant Manager something introduced in a later version? Which one did it start in?

Or is there something I can configure to in order to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Variant Manager was introduced in R2013b, see the [release notes](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/release-notes.html) (under R2013b, Component-Based Modeling).